# Mysql get results from todays date and forward

Tags: php, mysql, date-format

I am using opencart and wrote a new module to grab products that are coming soon. yet it still shows products even from before todays date.

my sql statement:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_available, "%M %d, %Y") as `comingdate` FROM `product` WHERE `date_available` >= '.DATE("Y-m-d").' ORDER BY `date_available` DESC LIMIT 20
```

what is wrong with that statement?

Comment: Why don't you use the date-field-type to store dates in the MySQL relation? they are made for it. Instead of parsing the string with the date() function you could just use the native `NOW()`

Comment: It's possible date() was just like a placeholder. He may also use this function to pass a future date. But if not, then yeah, NOW() is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date_available, '%M %d, %Y') as `comingdate` FROM `product` WHERE `date_available` >= '".date('Y-m-d')."' ORDER BY `date_available` DESC LIMIT 20"
```

Remember, date_available is a string. You need the single quotes there.

Comment: durrr thank you sir, always glad to have a fresh pair of eyes to catch my slips lol.